# Does lambda in Kotlin always hold reference to the object where it was created?

Tags: android, kotlin, lambda, memory-leaks, closures

I have a question about kotlin lambdas and implicit references to `this`. Lets look at this code:

```kotlin
class MyViewModel: ViewModel {
    val eventFlow = mutableSharedFlow<Unit>()
}

class MyFragment: Fragment() {
    val viewModel = MyViewModel()

    val lambda_1: (Unit) -> Unit = { Log.v("TAG", "Event happened") }
    val lambda_2: (Unit) -> Unit = { processEvent() }

    fun processEvent() {
        //do smth
    }
    
    override fun onCreate(bundle: Bundle?) {
        lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
            viewModel.eventFlow.collect(lambda_1)
        }
        lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
            viewModel.eventFlow.collect(lambda_2)
        }
    }
}
```

Please tell me if I'm correct or not:

1. `lambda_1` does NOT call any methods or variables of `MyFragment`, so it does NOT hold reference to `MyFragment` object.
2. `lambda_2` DOES call a method from `MyFragment`, so it DOES hold a reference to `MyFrgament` object.
3. If 2nd is correct, then when using such a lambda, we violate one of the points of MVVM ("ViewModel must not have reference to View"), because there is a reference chain `viewModel` -> `eventFlow` -> `lambda_2` -> `MyFragment`.

Tried to read byte code but couldn't figure out answers from it.

Answer (score 6):

1. Yes, this is correct. `lambda_1` doesn't need a reference to `MyFragment`, so it doesn't keep one. As a matter of fact, because the `lambda_1` could be entirely static, the Kotlin compiler creates a singleton and reuses the same instance for all instances of `MyFragment`.

2. This is also correct. `lambda_2` needs a reference to `MyFragment`, so it keeps one. In this specific case it works in a similar way to an inner class, so when `MyFragment` instantiates the lambda, it passes a reference to itself through a constructor. In general it is different as lambda holds references to any object it needs, no matter if it is the "outer" class or not.

3. To be honest, I'm not very familiar with MVVM, but I assume its restrictions are the same as with general good practices.

a). If your concern is around the application architecture and separation of concerns, so lower layer should not call the higher layer, then this case doesn't violate this rule. View only registers an event in viewmodel, but viewmodel still doesn't reference views directly and doesn't know them.

b). If your concern is that the instance of `MyFragment` is leaked, it can't be garbage collected, then this is not a problem in this specific case. `MyFragment` uses `lifecycleScope` when collecting the flow. When the fragment is destroyed, its `lifecycleScope` cancels all launched coroutines, flow collector is also cancelled, and as a result the lambda is not needed anymore and can be garbage collected.